# Apply jquery script to only one class at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

How can I apply this script to only one class at a time

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){



        // set up click/tap panels
        $('.click').toggle(function(){

            $(this).addClass('flip');
        },function(){
            $(this).removeClass('flip');
        });

        // set up block configuration
        $('.action').click(function(){;
            $('.card').addClass('flip');
        });
        $('.action2').click(function(){
            $('.card').removeClass('flip');
        });


});
```

When I click the action class all the card classes flip and I wanted to rotate one at a time.

My idea is to click on one and flip only that one, click on another and flip only that card not all the cards at the same time.

Comment: `toggle(fnc,fnc)` is deprecated in jQuery. You should avoid using it.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML? We can't help you without knowing the relationship between `.action` and `.card`.

Comment: <div class="card">


 <div class="front">
    <div class="action carouselDescriptionWrapper">
    <h4 itemprop="brand" class="colorBlack-94">Alexander Mcqueen</h4>
    <span itemprop="name"class="colorBlack-80">Printed dress</span>
    <div class="rotateicon">                      
    <img  class="imgCaroussel" src="imgs/rotateRight.png" width="16" height="16"  />
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="deleteicon">
    <img src="imgs/delete.png"  />
    </div>
    
   <img class="imgCaroussel" itemprop="image" src="imgs/_temp/1_70.jpg" width="70" height="93" alt="2" />
    </div>

Comment: my idea is to click on one and flip only that one, click on another and flip only that card not all the cards at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to flip the `.card` div that contains the action you clicked on, do:

```
    $('.action').click(function(){;
        $(this).closest(".card").addClass('flip');
    });
```

Comment: Or it could also be : `$(".card", this).addClass('flip');`

Comment: @Lostdreamer No, that goes the other way.

Comment: thanks my code now lokks like this  <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
 this doesn't seem to work to remove the class any ideas ? thanks a lot!  
   
   
   // set up click/tap panels
   $('.click').toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass('flip');
   },function(){
    $(this).removeClass('flip');
   });
   
   
      $('.action').click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".card").addClass('flip');
   });
   $('.action2').click(function(){
    $('.card').removeClass('flip');
   });
  
   
 });
</script>

Comment: Hard to tell if that's right since there's no formatting in comments. If my solution worked, indicate that by accepting the answer.

Comment: @Barmar Context comes after the coma when you want to set one. Thus my command still stand. Here jQuery Doc : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: @Lostdreamer Context will look for the card inside $(this), he wants to find the card that contains $(this). The search goes the wrong direction for his application.

Comment: @Barmar My misunderstanding then.

Comment: ` <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
   
   
   
   // set up click/tap panels
   $('.click').toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass('flip');
   },function(){
    $(this).removeClass('flip');
   });
   
   
      $('.action').click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".card").addClass('flip');
   });
   $('.action2').click(function(){
    $('.card').removeClass('flip');
   });
  
   
 });
</script> `

Comment: @Barmar it works when i first click it but i would like to click it again to close and it closes all items with that class...

Comment: @Lostdreamer i think you're right can you please help me with that code?

Comment: You need to use the `.closest()` code when removing the class, just like adding the class. I only showed one, I thought it would be obvious that you need to make the same change to the other.

Comment: Here is a working example based on the code you posted and Barmar solution (which is the good solution), notice the use of toggleClass this replace the need of multiple handlers : http://jsfiddle.net/JhPQa/

Answer (score 1):

Use a delay

```
$('.action').click(function(){
    $('.card').each(function(i, el) {
        setTimeout(function(){ $(this).addClass('flip'); }, i*300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle a class onclick, you can utilize toggleClass().

```
$(document).on("click", ".click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('flip');
});
```

Now if you want to flip one at a time. That is a little tough to know exactly what you want. I am guessing you want something like this.

```
$('.action').click(function(){;        
    var cards = $('.card');
    var current = cards.filter(".flip").removeClass('flip');
    var next = current.length===1 && next.index()+1<cards.length? current.next() : cards.first();
    next.addClass("flip");
});
```

Comment: my idea is to click on one and flip only that one, click on another and flip only that card not all the cards at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval()`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/tEupv/)**

```
var cards;
index = 0;
var interval1;
function repeat()
{
      cards.eq(index++).addClass('flip');
      if(index  == cards.length)
          clearInterval(interval1);
}
$('.action').click(function(){
    cards = $('.card');
    interval1 = setInterval(repeat, 1000);
});
```